# Need help in mapping space key to any of the Alt keys

Tags: keyboard, remapping

My space bar is not working.  using external keyboard, which is really  hard. Please advice me on mapping space key to alt key left or right in normal mode(I dont understand command prompt). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try the XKB extension.
Go onto your terminal and type:

`sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`

The terminal will ask you for your passwor(Linux does not display your typing in terminal when entering a password, don't worry, it is entering the text!)

You should now see a list of keys and there corresponding values

(ie. `key <ALT> {    [  Alter        ]   };`)
Keep scrolling down until you find the ALT option.
Rename the corresponding value, in this case Alter, with "Space".
Press CTRL+O and then CTRL+X
Hope this helps